# Config eleventy data folder for github

Tags: github, eleventy

How to config the _data folder to another git repository? The whole folder is clone from github and want to continue due to easy update. But the _data folder need to sync with another data repository. How can I config it?

Actually just one yaml file : _data/authorlist.yaml

What to put into package.js if want a script to sync the yaml file with github?

Thank you.

Comment: it would be great to include specific directory listing and .eventy.js config file to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to keep a shared repository of data files that you can use in multiple projects. This will allow you to keep a reference to the data repository in your projects, and pull updates to this repository with a single command. The great thing is that submodules are a built-in feature of Git, so it's independent of any NPM scripts, environments (like a bash script would be) or frameworks. See the link above for documentation on how to set up and work with submodules.